# Thousand separator in symfony input form

Tags: forms, symfony, input, format

I have in my symfony5 form input

```
->add('required_amount', IntegerType::class, [
                'label' => 'Požadovaná částka',
                'grouping' => true,
            ]);
```

when run form the thousand sepator isn dispaly on typing number
[image]

whatis wrong in my code, may I use number format in input in form in symfony

Answer (score 1):

I copy your code and runs just fine to my 4.4.4 symfony project. If you submit this form the output will be `1,000,000` or `1.000.000` depending on your locale value default set in `.env` file. The grouping property is in [IntegerType](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/forms/types/integer.html#grouping) , [MoneyType](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/forms/types/money.html#grouping) and [NumberType](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/forms/types/number.html#grouping) and do the same in all this classes , so this is not your problem. If you describe something in client side (as you type the numbers to add the separator) you need to go with javascript not php, but i don't thinks this is the case.

Comment: Yes I need display thousand separator when user is typing number to form, not on submit.